# Calling Harbinger price contract get method in taquito

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, taquito

I am trying to call the get method of the coinbase normalizer harbinger price contract (KT1AdbYiPYb5hDuEuVrfxmFehtnBCXv4Np7r).

Is this the correct way to call the get method, as it doesn't seem to be working for me.

const c = await Tezos.wallet.at('KT1AdbYiPYb5hDuEuVrfxmFehtnBCXv4Np7r');

const op = await c.methods.get("XTZ-USD", "<contract_address>%<callback_name>").send();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, Taquito doesn't support calling entrypoints that take a value of type `contract` as a parameter, so it won't be possible to call the `get` entrypoint of this contract.

Comment: thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

The lambda view feature allows retrieving data via a contract's view method. Here is a link to the documentation: https://tezostaquito.io/docs/lambda_view

Here is an example with a similar contract on granadanet:

```
const contract = await Tezos.contract.at('KT1AQuWowr3WKwF69oTGcKaJrMajic3CKwR2');
const response = await contract.views.get('ETH-USD').read();
```

The returned value is:

```
{
  "0": "ETH-USD",
  "1": "2021-09-13T16:50:00.000Z",
  "2": "3194778043"
}
```